# How to use stdin in powershell to use git commit-tree?

Tags: git, powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that uses the git commit-tree command but it's documentation says (http://schacon.github.com/git/git-commit-tree.html):

> A commit comment is read from stdin. If a changelog entry is not
>   provided via "<" redirection, git commit-tree will just wait for one
>   to be entered and terminated with ^D.

Is writing to stdin like this possible in powershell somehow? Is there some work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't support stdin redirection (using `<`).  It does support stdin piping e.g.:

```
Get-Date | exe_that_takes_stdin.exe
```

If your git command doesn't work that way (perhaps uses normal stdin for something else), check out this [blog post](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/james/fun-with-powershell-plink-cisco-ios-and-powershell/).  It looks like they're shelling out to cmd.exe for the stdin redirection support.